# What's the correct way to get HTML from an AJAX Response in JSON Format?

Tags: ajax, json, html-encode

I have an AJAX request that creates a 'post', and upon successful post, I want to get HTML to inject back into the DOM. Right now I'm returning a JSON array that details success/error, and when I have a success I also include the HTML for the post in the response. So, I parse the response as JSON, and set a key in the JSON array to a bunch of HTML Code.

Naturally, the HTML code is making the JSON array break -- what should I do to escape it (or is there a better way to do this?). I get an AJAX response with a JSON array like so:

```
[{response:"success"},{html:'<div class="this is going to break...
```

Thanks!

Comment: only a single quote in your html should break the json. and ideally, you should be using a json-conversion library to do the conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what you're probably used to in JavaScript, ' can't begin a string in JSON. It's strictly a ". Single quotes *work* when you're passing JSON to JavaScript.. much like `<br>` *works* when you want to put an XHTML line break.

So, use " to open the HTML string, and sanitize your quotes with \".

[json.org](http://json.org/) has more info WRT what you should sanitize. Though the list of special characters isn't long, it's probably best to use a library like Anurag suggests in a comment.

Comment: I should probably clarify: single quotes *work* when you're passing JSON to JavaScript.. much like <br> *works* when you want to put an XHTML line break.

Comment: you should have edited your question instead of commenting it.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from escaping double quotes as mention by BranTheMan, newlines also break JSON strings. You need to replace newlines with `\n`.

Personally I've found this to be enough:

```
// Don't know what your serverside language is, example in javascript syntax:

print(encodeJSON({
    response : "success",
    html : htmlString.replace(/\n/g,'\\n').replace(/"/g,'\\"')
}));
```